# Android: How NOT to save instance state?

Tags: java, android, webview, instance, bundle

My app has login, once the access is granted, it creates a new html file to the sdcard, the output or the appearance of that html file depends on the account of the logger.

After writing, the app goes to the next activity

```
        Intent nextActivity = new Intent(MyMainAct.this, AppView.class);
        startActivity(nextActivity);
```

the AppView class is the next activity in which the UI is a webview. It views the html created on login.

When I click "login as different user" button, I go back to the Main Activity which is MyMainAct. I use the following code:

```
        Intent nextActivity = new Intent(AppView.this, MyMainAct.class);
        startActivity(nextActivity);
```

When I logged in again (as different user), I expected a different UI since the html created is different. But it did not happen. The same html of the first logger is presented by the webview.

I looked into the html code created by the second logger, it is different from the first. but the webview presents the html of the first logger.

Is it about instance state? That's what I think, that's why I don't want to save instance state (bundle).

**EDIT:**

How do I ignore savedInstanceState of my App?

my MainActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
```

my AppView Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: So, your app creates a new html for each login? Or for each user?

Comment: Thank you for your response Gab, yes it creates an updated html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that when user chooses the "login as different user" option, activity showing the HTML is `finish`ed (i.e. call the `finish` method on it). If you then ignore the `savedInstanceState` parameter in its `onCreate` event (which you likely do, I presume), the next time this activity is started it will be totally new instance of it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Xion, sorry for the noob question but how do I ignore savedInstanceState? And so do you mean, I have to call finish(); before Intent nextActivity = new Intent(AppView.this, MyMainAct.class);
startActivity(nextActivity); ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Before you invoke the main activity, you should `finish();` the current one (the one with HTML). As for ignoring `savedInstanceState`, well... ignore it :) If you didn't use it in any way in your HTML activity, just continue this way. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi Xion, can you give me a sample code on how to ignore the saveInstanceState? I updated the question...

Comment: Your `onCreate` method (containing just the `super` call) is totally fine when it comes to that. What I meant is simply not using the `savedInstanceState` contents at all to restore any activity state (e.g. the HTML contents of your view).

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works.

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(AppView.this, MyMainAct.class);
startActivity(nextActivity);
finish();
```

Comment: In your `AppView` activity, how/when do you load the HTML file?

Comment: I use webview, I use the code in this link http://codeofaninja.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-view-webpage-inside-your-android.html