# Android: How to ignore or disable savedInstanceState?

Tags: java, android, instance, state

I want to ignore or disable savedInstanceState so that the state of current activity won't save when I go to the next activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but why [it doesn't work here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197594/android-how-not-to-save-instance-state/)? It seemed like the instance is still saved.

Comment: Actually, the instance is saved, but you don't use it.

Answer (score 13):

Write this line in your activity xml file:

```
    android:saveEnabled="false"
```

Comment: This will not save instance state for the activity, but its children may still be saving and restoring state, which was the case for me. I had to put `android:saveEnabled="false"` on the individual xml elements that I didn't want to save state.

Answer (score 9):

Or this:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override `onRestoreInstanceState` without calling the super version

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //Just leave it empty
    }
```

Comment: But then you're not addressing the potential `TransactionTooLargeException` that occurs when saving instance state: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37103380

Comment: @GavinWright Thanks for sharing this. I didn't know that saving state may produce such issue. Btw, instead of my provided answer, is it possible to override `onSaveInstanceState` without calling `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)` as an answer to this question?